# How To Parse You Tube Code in php

Tags: php, regex

what I need

- i need 11 digit code that should be appended in you tube url.

  ```
   like www.youtube.com/embed/XzqagJTsNrc.
  ```

source code

```
 $url= htmlentities($this->linkify($row['tweetText']));

 $youtube=explode(' ',$url).
```

array output.

```
 Array
(
[0] => VW
[1] => @
[2] => European
[3] => Motor
[4] => Show
[5] => Brussels
[6] => -
[7] => Behind
[8] => the
[9] => scene
[10] => (part
[11] => 1):
[12] => &amp;nbsp;&lt;a
[13] => class=&quot;twtlnk&quot;
[14] => rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;
[15] => href=&quot;http://youtu.be/XzqagJTsNrc&quot;
[16] => target=\&quot;_blank\&quot;&gt;http://youtu.be/XzqagJTsNrc&lt;/a&gt;&nbsp;
[17] => via
[18] => &amp;nbsp;&lt;a
[19] => class=&quot;twthand&quot;
[20] => href=&quot;https://twitter.com/youtube&quot;
[21] => rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;
[22] => target=\&quot;_blank\&quot;
[23] => &gt;@youtube&lt;/a&gt;
)
```

i have tried using regex

```
           $text = preg_replace('~

            https?://         # Required scheme. Either http or https.
            (?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)? # Optional subdomain.
            (?:               # Group host alternatives.
            youtu\.be/      # Either youtu.be,
            | youtube         # or youtube.com or
            (?:-nocookie)?  # youtube-nocookie.com
            \.com           # followed by
            \S*             # Allow anything up to VIDEO_ID,
            [^\w\s-]       # but char before ID is non-ID char.
            )                 # End host alternatives.
            ([\w-]{11})      # $1: VIDEO_ID is exactly 11 chars.
            (?=[^\w-]|$)     # Assert next char is non-ID or EOS.
            (?!               # Assert URL is not pre-linked.
            [?=&+%\w.-]*    # Allow URL (query) remainder.
            (?:             # Group pre-linked alternatives.
            [\'"][^<>]*>  # Either inside a start tag,
            | </a>          # or inside <a> element text contents.
            )               # End recognized pre-linked alts.
            )                 # End negative lookahead assertion.
            [?=&+%\w.-]*        # Consume any URL (query) remainder.
            ~ix', 
            '<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$1">$1</a>',
            $youtube);

            print_r($text);
```

array return

```
  Array
 (
[0] => VW
[1] => @
[2] => European
[3] => Motor
[4] => Show
[5] => Brussels
[6] => -
[7] => Behind
[8] => the
[9] => scene
[10] => (part
[11] => 1):
[12] => &amp;nbsp;&lt;a
[13] => class=&quot;twtlnk&quot;
[14] => rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;
[15] => href=&quot;<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzqagJTsNrc">XzqagJTsNrc</a>;
[16] => target=\&quot;_blank\&quot;&gt;<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzqagJTsNrc">XzqagJTsNrc</a>;/a&gt;&nbsp;
[17] => via
[18] => &amp;nbsp;&lt;a
[19] => class=&quot;twthand&quot;
[20] => href=&quot;https://twitter.com/youtube&quot;
[21] => rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;
[22] => target=\&quot;_blank\&quot;
[23] => &gt;@youtube&lt;/a&gt;
```

)

- i just  need to fetch XzqagJTsNrc; on doing print_r($text[15]);
- it outputs   href="XzqagJTsNrc;
- but i need only   XzqagJTsNrc (11 digit charcter).

  ```
      how to parse   href="XzqagJTsNrc; (href =" ;)
  ```

Comment: i have asked  href="XzqagJTsNrc; how to remove href=" and ; from code

Comment: which means parsing of youtube code, if you remove `href="` and `;` only youtube code is left :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `preg_match`

```
$url = $text[15];

if (preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match)) {
   $video_id = $match[1];
}

echo( $video_id);
```

It will not only match youtube but another ids as well

Answer (score 0):

Simple as that :

```
$var = 'href="XzqagJTsNrc;';
$youtube_id = substr($var, 6, 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need `XzqagJTsNrc`, then use `basename`:

```
$link = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/XzqagJTsNrc';
echo basename($link); // XzqagJTsNrc
```